# Github desktop does not start any more

Tags: github-desktop, windows-11

in the last days github desktop started alright.
but doday it does not work any more...
most tries the window won´t open and sometimes an empty white window appears
I use Windows 11 but i cannot find out the version number from github desktop because it does not start.
it throws errors in the log:

> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.014Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 2
> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.015Z - error: [main] Malformed launch arguments received: C:\ProgramData\maxi_\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\GitHubDesktop.exe,--squirrel-firstrun
> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.027Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 3
> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.027Z - error: [main] Malformed launch arguments received: C:\Users\maxi_\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\GitHubDesktop.exe,--squirrel-firstrun,--allow-file-access-from-files
> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.485Z - error: [ui] PullRequestCoordinator: Error loading repositories
> 2022-04-12T19:44:07.864Z - info: [ui] Subscribed 'Drachenbauer' to Alive channel
> 2022-04-12T19:45:10.098Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 2
> 2022-04-12T19:45:10.099Z - error: [main] Malformed launch arguments received: C:\Users\maxi_\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\GitHubDesktop.exe,--squirrel-firstrun
> 2022-04-12T19:45:10.413Z - error: [ui] PullRequestCoordinator: Error loading repositories
> 2022-04-12T19:45:10.806Z - info: [ui] Subscribed 'Drachenbauer' to Alive channel
> 2022-04-12T19:47:08.281Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 2
> 2022-04-12T19:47:08.282Z - error: [main] Malformed launch arguments received: C:\Users\maxi_\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\GitHubDesktop.exe,--allow-file-access-from-files

my actual repositories are games, that i work on in godot.

https://github.com/Drachenbauer/Sokoban

https://github.com/Drachenbauer/3D-Sokoban

what is wrong here?

What can i do?

Comment: `--squirrel-firstrun` is a very odd argument to have :). Did you try checking the properties of the shortcut file or start menu entry you are using to launch it ? They might have some extra args in it.

Comment: there was something about setup. i found the actual aplication-file under user/Name/Local/GitHubDesktop. But it also does not start. now i get this:

Comment: 2022-04-12T20:29:26.541Z - error: [ui] PullRequestCoordinator: Error loading repositories 2022-04-12T20:29:26.921Z - info: [ui] Subscribed 'Drachenbauer' to Alive channel 2022-04-12T20:29:47.200Z - info: [main] Received possible protocol arguments: 2 2022-04-12T20:29:47.200Z - error: [main] Malformed launch arguments received: C:\Users\maxi_\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\GitHubDesktop.exe,--allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: Without github desktop i don´t know how to push the actual changes on my games to the online repositories to show their actual state...

Comment: Did not see your replies on this. You may have fixed your issues already but looking at the output you shared in comments I noticed a "," as well after the exe. Again can you check the properties of this exe file under username/Local/GitHubDesktop ? I cannot think of any other reason this type of error might come. Otherwise you could try reinstalling ?

Comment: Additionally, there are other alternative tools out there other than GitHub Desktop that you can try. They're listed here: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows
Worst comes to worst you can embrace the command line life and learn `git`, which is what all these tools run in the back :) For example, if your workflow involves only pushing and pulling commits you should be able to make do with just add, commit, push, pull, status and log commands.

Answer (score 6):

Open the github from this url

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin\github.bat
```

Comment: this did help to run. after update worked from desktop icon as usual

Answer (score 0):

this morning I had the same issue and I couldn't make it run, I downloaded again the githubdesktopsetup-x64.exe from the original site, ran it, and now it works again somehow.

I noticed the folder in appdata/local/githubdesktop now only has a folder for the 2.9.14 app instead of like 3-4 folders for other older versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post was made a while back, but here's what worked for me if it's still relevant:
Delete GitHub Desktop files from two locations:

Users/-your user name-/AppData/Local and

Users/-your user name-/AppData/Roaming.
Then, remove the program via Control Panel so all the residual files can be deleted.

Then, find the install file for version 2.9.5 from the web. Installing that version worked for me. I hope it works for you as well.